# How to parse animations.samplers.input from gltf

Tags: gltf

The spec explains the `animations.samplers.input` property as:

> The index of an accessor containing keyframe input values, e.g., time. That accessor must have componentType FLOAT. The values represent time in seconds with time[0] >= 0.0, and strictly increasing values, i.e., time[n + 1] > time[n].

However, I'm having a bit of trouble understanding this from the first basic example on the demo repo, [Animated Triangle](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/AnimatedTriangle)

Specifically, if we bring the relevant binary data for the animation from [animation.bin](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/master/2.0/AnimatedTriangle/glTF/animation.bin) and decode it into a `Float32Array`, we get the following list of values:

```
[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.7070000171661377, 0.7070000171661377, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.7070000171661377, -0.7070000171661377, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

This of course does not make sense in light of "strictly increasing values".

**What am I misunderstanding here? How are these values meant to be used (in combination with `output`) in order to update the rotation over time?**

Note that animation.bin is the view referenced from the `input` sampler. In other words, from [the gltf](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/master/2.0/AnimatedTriangle/glTF/AnimatedTriangle.gltf)

- input == accessor 2
- accessor 2 == bufferView 2
- bufferView 2 == bytes(0-100) from buffer 1
- buffer 1 == animation.bin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've decoded too far.  Although bufferView 2 is bytes 0 to 100, accessor 2 does not call for all those bytes.  Here's accessor 2:

```
{
  "bufferView" : 2,
  "byteOffset" : 0,
  "componentType" : 5126,
  "count" : 5,
  "type" : "SCALAR",
  "max" : [ 1.0 ],
  "min" : [ 0.0 ]
},
```

Note the `count: 5` in there.  Count is defined as:

> The number of attributes referenced by this accessor, not to be confused with the number of bytes or number of components.

So, accesessor 2 is the first five `SCALAR` values from offset 0 in bufferView 2, namely the first five numbers from your decoded output above:

```
[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
```

FWIW, there are tools to help investigate glTF binary files.  Here's the "Peek Definition" function from VSCode's glTF extension:

[image: Decoded accessor]

(Disclaimer, I'm one of the authors of this extension, although I did not write this decode feature myself).